# HTTP request to OpenID Provider service failed while downloading CORDEX simulation using wgetxxxx.sh script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, esgf

I want to download data cordex simulations from ESGF server using script provided in their website, but when I launch the script wgetxxx.sh it returns this error HTTP request to OpenID Provider service failed.
I use ubuntu 20.04,  Wget 1.20.3, I provide my openid and password as well.

Here is the error:

```
Running wget-20230527204009.sh version: 1.3.2
Use wget-20230527204009.sh -h for help.

Script created for 11 file(s)
(The count won't match if you manually edit this file!)



Enter your openid : https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/esgf-idp/openid/hchaabani@um6p 
Enter password : 

snc_EUR-11_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_IPSL-WRF381P_v2_day_19510101-19551231.nc ...Downloading

Retrying....


ERROR : Retry failed.

download failed
snc_EUR-11_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_IPSL-WRF381P_v2_day_19560101-19601231.nc ...Downloading
ERROR : HTTP request to OpenID Provider service failed.
download failed
```

I try this command `bash ./wget-20230527204009.sh -H` and I am expecting the data to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on the same server. When I retried it worked. I think maybe the issue was that I was trying to download from multiple shells in parallel.